# Pick bookmap title to body header

Tags: xslt, apache-fop, dita-ot

I am unable to retrieve bookmap title to body header . I don't know the proper solution of it.

I used in `<fo:retrieve-marker`in `body-odd-header` but it didn't worked. From where will I get reference to use `<fo:retrieve-marker` or any other mode to show bookmap title from dita map in PDF body page header ?

Comment: you have to define marker with value in body also to retrive header

Comment: @Rupesh I think I am doing something wrong with `<fo:retrieve-marker` syntax. Can you show some example for the proper syntax how to retrieve class value.